# PHP - отправить документ сразу на принтер без Javascript

Tags: php, печать

Приложение - Web. Формирует чеки на сервере. 
Задача - отправить документ на печать из приложения с помощью PHP, отравляя документ на расшаренный принтер - IP : port.

Ответы о том, что печатать надо с помощью JAVA, писать не стоит. Интересует именно данный конкретный вопрос!

Видел работающие примеры. Не получается реализовать подобное..
Копал в сторону расширения PECL для PHP - printer.
Функции работы с принтером описаны в документации PHP.

Но на оф. сайте PECL данного расширения для скачивания нет. 
Те, что находил в интернете не получается установить на домашний сервер.
(PHP 5.3.3, ось Win 7).
На рабочем приложении используется Centos 6.6

Comment: Все зависит от принтера или сервера печати, а также от того, что вы хотите печатать. Я бы формировал pdf и отправлял на ftp-печать - так проще всего, но можно было бы и по IPP поднять печать

Comment: Дело в том, что принтеры - могут быть разные. От этого зависит способ реализации ?

Comment: Конечно. Если планируется зоопарк принтеров, рекомендую поручить разбираться с драйверами и перекодировкой между форматами службе CUPS, а ей уже скармливать файлы, в удобном для формирования на стороне PHP формате (в зависимости от задач я бы выбирал между растром PNG или JPEG или вектором PDF, SVG или даже HTML)

Answer (score 2):

На Centos попробуйте установить [lp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lp).

И дальше с помощью системых вызовов вы можете делегировать всю работу этой утилите:

```
exec('/usr/bin/lp -d myprinter -o scaling=200 %filename%', $output, $status);
```

Comment: На сколько я понял, что CUPS это аналог lp ?
Опыта нет при работе не с CUPS , не lp..
На сколько я понимаю CUPS немного легче для понимания ?

Comment: не совсем. cups это сервер печати. Устанавливая cups у вас появится веб интерфейс на локальном хосте  + куча зависимостей, с помощью которого можно управлять принтерами, отправлять на печать и тд. У него есть API , которое можно использовать для ваших целей, но он намного более громоздкий

Comment: Извините за возможно глупые вопросы, web приложение написанное на php+Java может вызывать системные вызовы для lp? Как это реализовать ? Напишите пожалуйста простейший пример

Comment: я же написал в ответе. http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php
php выполнит внешнюю программу (которая предварительно должна быть установлена на вашу ОС). Аналоги конечно должны быть и в Java.
Главное не забывать , что как правило веб приложение запускается от имени другого пользователя (apache, www-data) , поэтому права для вашей *внешней* программы должны быть сконфигурированы соответствующим образом